# How can I add button to my sublist?

Tags: netsuite

I want to add a button on the inline edit set of buttons. For instance, on the Opportunity's item sublist I want to insert a button. I would prefer it to go after the "Add" button.

I originally tried this but it put a button on top set of buttons above the list. I can live with that but would prefer it in the inline set of buttons.

```
var list = form.getSubList("item");
list.addButton('custpage_customconfigurebutton', 'Configure', 'customrecord_configurator');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The addButton method only works if you want to add the button alongside the Add Multiple Upsell Items. You cannot add a button alongside the Add and Cancel or on the line level